# Xamarin.Forms + native library OpenCV

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to write an application using Xamarin.Forms. But I need to connect to the project native library OpenCV.
In tutorial i see how connect to the ios or android project. But I want use this native library in share code.

Library OpenCV has Android, Linux, Windows, iOS and Source Code versions. I would like to write code for this library once.

this is url for this library http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Please, help solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to have one codebase when using native bindings on iOS and Android. However, you can automate everything by using SWIG (http://www.swig.org). Short example here: http://blog.reblochon.org/2013/01/c-bindings-for-monotouch-using-swig.html

There's also .NET port of OpenCV called EMGU which works fine with Xamarin.

Comment: hellow Daniel. EMGU work width xamarin.ios or xamarin.android but no xamarin.forms.

Comment: Yes, but Xamarin.Forms uses Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS underneath. You could then make a common interface for functionality that you're interested and make an implementation for each platform and use it trough dependency injection.